# Show Message in Woocommerce Cart only for specific product variation Attribute

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product-variations

I am adding a custom message to the Cart page, but so that it only appears if an added product has a custom variation atribute selected.

After researching I came up to:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart', 'wnd_after_cart' ); 
function wnd_after_cart() { 
    if($attribute_slug == 'no_review'){ 
        echo '<div class="wnd_after_cart"><h4>There will be no item manual review</h4><br /> </div>';
    }
}
```

But its not working. Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart', 'wnd_after_cart' ); 
function wnd_after_cart() { 
    echo '<div class="wnd_after_cart"><h4>There will be no item manual review</h4><br /> </div>'; 
}
```

Works very well, but I can't get the code to display the message only IF my custom attribute is selected.

Any help is appreciated…

**Edit:**

I set my product Atributes (example:Shirt size, Slug:'Shirt_Size') , and their variations within this atribute (Example: S (Slug:'Size_S'), M(Slug:'Size_M'), XL(Slug:'Size_XL') )

I'm trying to display the message when a specific Attribute Variation is selected (Example: The slug for S, 'Size_S')

I'm using clothes/shirt sizes since its a more common example to help illustrate.

In case I didn't explain very well, basically the code is searching for the attribute slug that you can see here in this video at 0:23 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QyMuq-WkV0o

But I'm trying to make it search for the slugs of the attribute variations that can be seen at 0:35 
(the attribute attributes, or attribute variations, or attribute childs, I'm not sure what to name them)

@LoicTheAztec code seems to be working very well, but it's searching for the slug of the attribute (Shirt_Size), and not for the attribute variations shown previosly. 
When I set the code to find 'Shirt_size', it will disply the message, but when I set it to find 'Size_S', it stops working.

Did this make sense?
Thank you for the attention and advice once again.

Comment: Where's the logic you get that $attribute_slug ? Whats it's value?

Comment: The attribute slug can't be `Shirt_Size` … it should be `shirt_size` or `shirt-size` but NOT `Shirt_Size`… slugs are always in lowercase without special characters, spaces … So you should revisit all your attributes and let woocommerce make the slugs itself (same thing for the terms for each product attribute)… **Ideally for SIZE product attribute you should have just `"Size"` (slug ==> `"size"`) and the terms slugs should be `"s"`, `"m"`, `"xl"`**

Answer (score 1):

There is some missing code like getting your `$attribute_slug` from variations in cart items:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart', 'checking_variation_attributes_message' );
function checking_variation_attributes_message() {
    $found = false;
    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        if( ! $product->is_type('variation')){
            continue; // Jump to next cart item
        }
        $variation_attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes();
        foreach ( $variation_attributes as $variation_attribute => $term_slug ){
            $attribute_slug = str_replace('attribute_pa_', '', $variation_attribute);

            if( $attribute_slug == 'no_review' ){
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if($found){
        echo '<div class="wnd_after_cart"><h4>There will be no item manual review</h4><br /> </div>';
    }
}
```

Update: Or if you are looking for a product attribute **term slug** instead, use it this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart', 'checking_variation_attributes_message' );
function checking_variation_attributes_message() {
    $found = false;
    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        if( ! $product->is_type('variation')){
            continue; // Jump to next cart item
        }
        $variation_attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes();
        foreach ( $variation_attributes as $variation_attribute => $term_slug ){
            $attribute_slug = str_replace('attribute_pa_', '', $variation_attribute);

            if( $term_slug == 'no_review' ){
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if($found){
        echo '<div class="wnd_after_cart"><h4>There will be no item manual review</h4><br /> </div>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

Comment: Well I never expected to be missing so much, I feel frustrated that I can't understand the logic behind some of what is here. 
So many thanks Loic for your input, although after adding that code I am getting the error: https://imgur.com/gTfjpRL
(It's a local instalation so I can't at the moment redirect you to it, but if there is anything I can do just let me know)

Do you have any idea why could be causing this?

Thank you very much in advance for the attention and advice.

Comment: @JaimeMatos Ok I have found the problem and updated the code try it again please… Thanks

Comment: thank you very much once again for your input. Unfortunately it's still giving me an error https://imgur.com/a/gc4zO
But this error only shows on my offline instalation.

I placed the website live on a test domain if you wish to take a look at it https://blog.impressao3dportugal.pt/cart/
And on this online version there is no error message at all but there is also no custom message.

I understand if the solution might be too complicated, but I will gladly send you a donation if you save my day!

Comment: @JaimeMatos Sorry again … I have dust in the eyes… Updated again. it was simply `$product = $cart_item['data'];` instead of `$product = $cart_item['data']->get_product();`

Comment: I think i figured out what is wrong. 
It seems this code is seeking for the attribute itself, because if I place the slug of the attribute, then it works. But the atribute is always there (Ex: clothes size), but not the variation of the/inside the attribute (ex: S, M, XL..)

My slug 'no_review' is the "child"/bellow/variation of the attribute, as I explained previously as S, M XL), and the code seems to be searching for the attribute slug itself, because if I change it for it then it works, except the message is always there since the attribute too.
Do you know what I mean?

Comment: @JaimeMatos No sorry I don't… you should add an edit at the end of your question with details and may be a real example… then notify me here…

Comment: just updated the main post with an Edit, in hopes that I will make more sense now

Comment: @JaimeMatos I have maid an update (2 similar different functions) as it seems that you want to use a product attribute term slug value in the `if` statement instead of the product attribute slug… right? if it's the case use the 2nd one…