# Hide odd thumbnails from product gallery for specific product attribute term name selection

Tags: php, jquery, html, woocommerce, cart

I am trying to hide the odd thumbnails in my product pages on attribute selection.

When the attribute with the value `Electronics Protection` is selected, it should hide the odd thumbnails in the Yith Magnifier Gallery which has the CSS class `yith_magnifier_gallery`.

I found the code from the answer in the following thread: [Show Message in Woocommerce Cart only for specific product variation Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49509774/show-message-in-woocommerce-cart-only-for-specific-product-variation-attribute)

And I edited it a bit. But I feel that there are mistakes in my code because it's giving the following error when I put the code in `functions.php`.

> This page isn’t working
>
> powermatic7.com is currently unable to handle this request.
>
> HTTP ERROR 500

Below is my code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart', 'hide_thumbs_based_on_variation' );
function hide_thumbs_based_on_variation() {
    $found = false;
    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        if( ! $product->is_type('variation')){
            continue; // Jump to next cart item
        }
        $variation_attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes();
        foreach ( $variation_attributes as $variation_attribute => $term_value ){
            $attribute_slug = str_replace('attribute_pa_', '', $variation_attribute);

            if( $term_value == 'Electronics Protection' ){
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if($found){
        $(".yith_magnifier_gallery img:nth-child(odd)").hide();
    }
}
```

And the HTML code of the Yith Magnifier Gallery:

```
<div class="yith_magnifier_gallery">
    <img src="#" />
    <img src="#" />
    <img src="#" />
    <img src="#" />
    <img src="#" />
    <img src="#" />
</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Because you are mixing JavaScript with PHP

Comment: @CodeSpirit Could you please give a hint as to where this error could be corrected? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you need the modification in product single page, but you are trying cart hook. You need to use any of **product single page hook**. Add this in your theme's 'functions.php'. Change `attribute_id` given below to appropriate one.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_variations_form' , 'woocommerce_show_hide_images_gallery', 5 );

function woocommerce_show_hide_images_gallery() {      
    global $product;
    if( $product->is_type('variable') ){
    ?>
    <script>
    var attribute_id = 'power-system'; // change attribute id here
    function showHideImages(attval)
    {
        if(attval)
        {
            var match_data = 'Electronics Protection';  // change attribute value here

            if(attval.toUpperCase()==match_data.toUpperCase())      
                jQuery(".yith_magnifier_gallery img:odd").parent().hide();
            else
                jQuery(".yith_magnifier_gallery img:odd").parent().show();
        }
    }

    //select box change
    jQuery("#"+attribute_id).change(function(){
        showHideImages( jQuery(this).val() );
    });

    //swatch click
    jQuery(".swatchinput label[selectid=" + attribute_id + "]").click(function(){
        showHideImages( jQuery(this).data('option') );
    });

    //select box & swatch change on page load (if you are getting back again)
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        showHideImages( jQuery("#"+attribute_id).val() );
        showHideImages( jQuery(".swatchinput label.selectedswatch[selectid=" + attribute_id + "]").data('option') );
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    }
}
```

Seems like you are using some custom plugin to display the attributes in your site and so I have added that extra code too. Hope 'swatch' related codes were not necessary and feel free to remove in that case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This works. However, when it hides the thumbnails, the other thumbnails stay in their place and do not shift to the left. Once the thumbnails are hidden, can we also move the remaining thumbnails to the left so there are no blank spaces between the visible thumbnails?

Comment: Can you able to share the URL to check?

Comment: Never mind, I updated my answer, try and let me know.

Comment: I have edited the code a bit and made some CSS changes to achieve what I wanted. Thanks for guiding me in the correct direction. Your answer has been accepted.

Answer (score 2):

> The linked code answer in your question need to be used in **exclusively in Cart page**.
>
> **So it will not work anyways on single product pages.**

You need to target single product pages for variable products only.

The following code use **a very light SQL query** and will hide ODD thumbnails, when a selected variation ID has the attribute term name value **"Electronics Protection"**:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer' , 'hide_thumbs_based_on_variation', 5 );
function hide_thumbs_based_on_variation() {
    global $product, $wpdb;

    // Only on single product pages and for variable product type
    if( ! ( is_product() && $product->is_type('variable') ) )
        return; // Exit

    // HERE the defined product attribute term name
    $term_name = 'Electronics Protection';

    // SQL query: Find the corresponding Variation Ids for the defined term name
    $variation_ids = $wpdb->get_col( "
        SELECT pm.post_id
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm
        JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}terms as t ON pm.meta_value = t.slug
        JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p ON pm.post_id = p.ID
        WHERE t.name = '$term_name'
        AND p.post_parent = '{$product->get_id()}'
    " );

    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        var a  = <?php echo json_encode($variation_ids) ?>,     b = 'input.variation_id';

        // Show hide thumbnails utility function
        function showHideThumbs(){
            $.each( a, function(ind, variationID){
                if( $(b).val() == variationID ){
                    $(".yith_magnifier_gallery > img:nth-child(odd)").hide();
                    return;
                } else {
                    $(".yith_magnifier_gallery > img:nth-child(odd)").show();
                }
            });
        }

        // On start, once the DOM is loaded (with a mandatory very light delay)
        setTimeout(function(){
            showHideThumbs();
        }, 100);

        // Live event: On product attribute select field change
        $('form.variations_form').on( 'blur', 'select', function(){
            showHideThumbs();
        })
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).

Tested and works with the given html gallery structure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works. But I have used @Outsource WordPress 's answer as it does not use a SQL query. I have edited it a bit and made some CSS changes to achieve what I wanted. Wish I could award you both the bounty! Thanks. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

**try this:** maybe this would help you

```
 if($found){
    var gallery = document.querySelector(".yith_magnifier_gallery");
    images = gallery.children;
    for ( i=1; i<=images.length; i++){
        if( ( i % 2 ) != 0){
          images[i - 1].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but still returning the same error.

Answer (score 0):

First comment this line

```
 $(".yith_magnifier_gallery img:nth-child(odd)").hide();
```

like

```
/* $(".yith_magnifier_gallery img:nth-child(odd)").hide();*/
```

> Run the app and check if error still exists, if you  are still getting
>   error, it might be some other issue, not related to the code you
>   posted.

**If no error proceed like this.**

You need to call the JavaScript `$(".yith_magnifier_gallery img:nth-child(odd)").hide();` when your page loads. It should NOT be in your functions.php

Set a global variable at the end of your PHP function like this

$GLOBALS['jsVarFound'] = $found;

You dont need

```
if($found){
        $(".yith_magnifier_gallery img:nth-child(odd)").hide();
    }
```

instead put `$GLOBALS['jsVarFound'] = $found;` there

In your head tag or wherever after you load jQuery use this.

```
<script>
var isFound = "<?php echo($GLOBALS['jsVarFound']); >";
if(isFound == "1") {
   $(".yith_magnifier_gallery img:nth-child(odd)").hide();
}
</script>
```

this should work.